# Weird vector notation $\vec{v}=[1 \ 2 \ 3]^T$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

In a famous Engineering course in Brazil all of the vector (Analytic Geometry) material is written in the following fashion:

$$\vec{v}=[1  \ 2 \ 3]^T$$

represents what is commonly written as

$$\vec{v} = (1,2,3)$$

Is that notation from somewhere specific (a book, a country...)? Is it wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: What if the vector is $\vec{v}=(11,1,11)$? If we use that notation we would then write $\vec{v}=[11111]^T$. Or are there spaces in there between each entry  (i.e. $[11\, 1\, 11]^T$)?

Comment: I think in general people use the column vector notation(i.e the one with the "T" or tranpose) because of matrix multiplication in linear algebra and the row vector notation for coordinates.

Answer (score 3):

Both are acceptable.  The first example, $\vec{v}=[1  \ 2 \ 3]^T$, is the transpose of a row vector, or equivalently, a column vector.  The second example, $\vec{v} = (1,2,3)$, uses ordered set notation instead of matrix notation, but lists each component just the same.